# The requested application with ID xxxxxx was not found

Tags: google-play-games, leaderboard, google-developers-console

I 'm trying to post/get score from google play leaderboards

I met all the meta-tag from the documentation including my client id

`<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com" />`

I also have setup the google sign-in system and all is fine, however when I try to call the leaderboards API I get the message error: `The requested application with ID xxxxxx was not found`

I am calling the API like the mentioned in the doc

```
  gapi.client.request({
            path: '/games/v1/leaderboards/LEADERBOARD-ID',
            params: { maxResults: 3 },
            callback: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the problem is the missing argument to execute a request.

Try to use this [API requests](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#api-requests) method.

> gapi.client.Request
>
> An object encapsulating an HTTP request. This object is not
>   instantiated directly, rather it is returned by gapi.client.request.
>   There are two ways to execute a request. We recommend that you treat
>   the object as a [promise](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises) and use the `then` method, but you can also use
>   the execute method and pass in a callback.

You can refer to this [Github post](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1238) for additional reference.

> This message: W/AchievementAgent( 3558):
>   {"code":404,"errors":[{"message":"The requested application with ID
>   571707973781 was not found.","domain":"global","reason":"notFound "}]}
>   is a little cryptic but points to a mismatch with the auth
>   configuration on the console and the application.
>
> You'll want to double check the keystore SHA1 fingerprint of the
>   keystore you signed the app with and the one configured in the dev
>   console.
>
> It could also be the bundle ID, but that is hard to mess up since it
>   is part of the resource data used when running Setup for the plugin.
>
> Also, it could be that the player is not a tester for this game.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is that the game was not published yet, I tried to publish the beta version I can know reach the leaderboards but only from the tester accounts I added in my game console.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue, you need to publish the beta version of the game to be able to interact with the game scoreboard.

Note: In the beta version, only tester accounts added to the game can access the scoreboard.